# Множественная группировка по нескольким полям в Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Необходимо сгруппировать сущности `Deliveries` сразу по двум полям, а именно:

1) `Crew` (Или Crew.Id, даже не знаю, что в данном случае будет более уместно) - является навигационным свойством. (У каждой Delivery может быть 0 или 1 Crew).

2) `Date` - дата

```
Db.Deliveries.Where(d => d.CrewId != null)
             .GroupBy(d => new {d.Crew, d.Date})
             .OrderBy(d => d.Key)
             .ToList()
```

Всё хорошо, такой код вполне валиден. Но что нам передать в представление (`View`)? Какого типа будет представление? Ведь мне даже не удаётся получить тип просто для обычной переменной, хранящей результат данной группировки, например:

```
var Deliveries = Db.Deliveries.Where(d => d.CrewId != null)
                 .GroupBy(d => new {d.Crew, d.Date})
                 .OrderBy(d => d.Key)
                 .ToList();
```

Код валиден. Но что если я хочу избавиться от `var`?

```
List<IGrouping<{Crew:Crew, Date:DateTime}, Delivery>> Deliveries = Db.Deliveries
                                                     .Where(d => d.CrewId != null)
                                                     .GroupBy(d => new {d.Crew, d.Date})
                                                     .OrderBy(d => d.Key)
                                                     .ToList();
```

Например так - не получается. Может я не понимаю синтаксис, или ещё чего не догоняю... Не знаю куда копать. 
Пробовал и так `List<IGrouping<{Crew, DateTime}, Delivery>>`, тоже не то.

Всё это я веду к тому, что за тип у нас будет у представления, принимающего результат этой группировки. Мне уже всё равно, анонимный, не анонимный объект, строго или не строго типизированное представление.. На худой конец, меня бы устроил любой рабочий вариант, где результат группировки можно было бы как-то использовать в представлении. Также рад буду и любому костыльному решению, типа с использованием своих самописных классов или ещё чего. Но пока не догоняю как. Казалось бы, какой тип может подойти лучше, чем те, что есть в `.Net,` а именно интерфейсы `IGrouping` в сочетании с `List`.

Comment: Во view тип модели dynamic можете сделать

Comment: Сделаю @model dynamic
И? Дальше как использовать модель, если я не могу её ни к чему привести? Можете привести пример?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет-нет, вам придётся, судя по всему, сделать «настоящий» тип вместо `new {d.Crew, d.Date}`.

Попробуйте так:

```
public class DeliverableGroupContainer
{
    public Crew Crew;
    public DateTime Date;
    public List<Deliverable> Deliverables;
}

List<DeliverableGroupContainer> Deliveries =
         Db.Deliveries
           .Where(d => d.CrewId != null)
           .GroupBy(d => new {d.Crew, d.Date})
           .OrderBy(d => d.Key)
           .Select(g => new DeliverableGroupContainer()
                        {
                            Crew = g.Key.Crew,
                            Date = g.Key.Date,
                            Deliverables = g.ToList()
                        })
           .ToList();
```

Comment: Мегареспктище Вам! То что нужно! Лаконичней решения думаю нет и быть не может.

Comment: @RRRPro: отлично, одну проблему решили.